# Link applying over entire td instead it should apply only over the image

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am creating an eMailer, here I am adding a social-interaction bar(code given below).
The issue is that though I have positioned the image in the center of a table cell, the link that wraps it spans over the entire cell area.
Can anyone suggest a code tweak so that the link area is applied only on the image and not the cell it is in?

Code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td height="32px"><center>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com&#x22; target="_blank">
<img src="./images/youtube.png" alt="youtube icon" title="youtube" height="32px" width="32px">
</a>
</center></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How are you saying that it's getting applied over the entire TD?. If you add a text after center what happens?

Comment: Please don't use the `<center>` element. It doesn't exist in the current standard.

Comment: Yes, its applying over entire TD.
I have removed center tag and used css code "style="margin:0px auto;" to position the image in center instead. However the issue still persists.